# Less painful way to add a different icon to each link on a <li> (html list)

Tags: html, css, html-lists

take a look of this: http://jsfiddle.net/PFQke/

I want to add some icons to that menu system in a smart way, im not a front-end developer, so i suck at css.

This is what i like to have:

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: "Less painful way"? What's the more painful way? Your fiddle doesn't show any icons.

Comment: "Your fiddle doesn't show any icons" (if you read again the question...)

Comment: Is adding a separate class for each item the only way to do this?  Seems pretty taxing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding to each <li> a class like this:

```
<div id="vertmenu"> 
   <ul>
      <li class="home-ico"><a href="#" tabindex="1">Home</a></li>
```

Then add some css code:

```
#vertmenu .home-ico {
   background: url("path_to_img") no-repeat top left;
   padding: 2px 0 0 25px;
}
```

This is just an example, but you can start from this.
In example that padding has to be adjusted in case your icon is more than 25px large.

Comment: Be aware that using a selector like `div#vertmenu ul li.home-ico` is really inefficient. IDs are by definition unique, so adding the element type to the selector is redundant and unless you have class `home-ico` used on something other than a `<li>` adding that just slows the match down for no reason. Much better (if you actually need that much specificity) would be: `#vertmenu .home-ico`. Even faster, use a class or ID that is unique: `#vertmenu-home-ico`. [Writing Efficient CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Writing_Efficient_CSS)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link and everything! I'll edit my post and read the article!

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost use classes to differentiate items.

Those are different icons, so you need to give a different `url` attribute to the `background-image` property of each of those `<a>`. Even if you have them in a single image (sprites), you will still need to give them different coordinates each.

```
#vertmenu a.link1 {
  background-image: /* background image for a#1 */
}
#vertmenu a.link2 {
  background-image: /* background image for a#2 */
}
```

Do you use a single image for every icon (sprites)?

```
#vertmenu a {
  background-image: /* specify it only once */
}
#vertmenu a.link1 {
  background-position: /* background pos for a#1 */
}
#vertmenu a.link2 {
  background-position: /* background pos for a#2 */
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could insert your image in the div containing your menu, and use only one image. This way you will need only one css rule, but you won't have the rollover effect on the single images.

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JoseFaeti/zZPuH/).

Comment: Please don't abuse tabindex for this. Just add a classname in your html. It will save you a lot of trouble if you ever want to change the order of the items or want to add an item. Also don't use tabindex; ever, unless you absolutely 100% know what you are doing, and there is no other way of doing it.

Comment: @Gerben: indeed, I was just explaining how to add the rules. Edited my answer with the class advice.

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<ul id="vertmenu">
  <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="about"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  ...
  <li class="links"><a href="#">Links</a></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
#vertmenu {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12pt;
  width: 160px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
}
#vertmenu li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: none no-repeat left 50%;/* left and centered */
}
#vertmenu .home {
  background-image: url(home.jpg);/*specify image here*/
}
#vertmenu .about {
  background-image: url(about.jpg);
}
/* ... etc. ... */
#vertmenu a {
  font-size: .8em;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 0px 2px 20px;/* change 20px to width of icon+some padding*/
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666666;
  /*width:160px; not needed. also should have be 156px because of the 4px left padding */
}
#vertmenu a:hover, #vertmenu a:focus {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #eeeeee;/* will hide the icon!!*/
}
```